# GitLab CI: Get source branch after merge-request has been accepted

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, gitlab-ci, branching-and-merging

I have a master branch which is supposed to only get commits by merging either a "release/xxxxx" branch into it or by merging a "hotfix/xxxxx" branch into it.

The pipeline for a release branch builds a docker image and publishes it using the tag "beta".
The pipeline for a release branch builds a docker image and publishes it using the tag "hotfix".

The pipeline for the master simply re-tags either "beta" to "stable" (when a release branch has been merged into the master)  or "hotfix" to "stable" (when a hotfix branch has been merged into the master). Then it also creates a new git tag for that version and a release in gitlab. Finally the docker image gets deployed.

Currently the following happens:

- A merge request is created to merge "release/xxxxx" into "master".
- The pipeline starts automatically (before the merge request has been accepted and merged).
- The docker job parses the `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` variable to determine the source branch of the merge request was a release branch.
- The docker job then re-tags "beta" to "latest".
- The git tag job adds a version tag and gitlab release to the project.
- The deploy job deploys the docker image.

When the merge request is finally accepted the following happens:

- The pipeline starts again.
- The docker job parses `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` which is now empty and thus fails to determine the source branch for this merge.
- The docker job fails.

I think it's pretty obvious that I don't want to run all these jobs (especially the deploy job) before the merge request has been accepted.

But I can't think of a good way to only run the pipeline on the master after a merge-request has been accepted and then still be able to determine the source branch.

Comment: Can you please share your `gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: My actual `.gitlab-ci.yml` is a big mess handling up to 13 jobs per branch and there are way more than the 3 branches mentioned in my question. No to mention the fact that it includes a bunch of files from other non-public projects, uses custom non-public docker images and heavily relies on env vars set on a group and project level. There is no way I can share all that and the .gitlab-ci.yml alone wouldn't help anyone.

Comment: I understand your situation but It's hard for us to assume your configuration as pipeline and deployment both highly depend on yml file.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

*Using only information stored in git :*

when running after a merge request has been accepted, the HEAD commit should be the result of the merge, so `HEAD^2` should be the head commit of the branch that was merged.

You can have information on :

- the tags that point directly at this commit :

  ```
   git tag --points-at HEAD^2
  ```
- the branches that point directly at this commit :

  ```
   git branch --points-at HEAD^2    # for local branches
   git branch -r --points-at HEAD^2 # for remote branches
  ```
- the branches that contain this commit :

  ```
   git branch --contains HEAD^2    # for local branches
   git branch -r --contains HEAD^2 # for remote branches
  ```

*Using environment variables set by gitlab :*

after reading the [predefined variables doc page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), I was surprised not to find variables that would indicate that the job was triggered after a merge request was accepted.

You may look into gitlab's webhooks : [Merge requests events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#merge-request-events) ; these should provide enough information to identify what branches were involved in the merge request *after* it has been accepted.

[update] you can also use gitlab's API, see [@BastienSander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67298918/86072)

Comment: When I try your commands, i have a "error: malformed object name 'HEAD^2'"

Comment: @BastienSander : this means your current active commit is not a merge commit (`HEAD^2` means "the second parent of `HEAD`", which is only valid if `HEAD` is a merge commit)

Comment: This didnt work for me so I changed to `git log --skip=1 -1 `

Answer (score 6):

It seems you can do it through the API of gitlab.

Here is a curl example.

```
  - MR_BRANCH_LAST_COMMIT_SHA=$(
      curl -s \
        --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
        "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/commits/$CI_COMMIT_SHA" |\
        jq -r '.parent_ids | del(.[] | select(. == "'$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA'")) | .[-1]'
    )
  - MR_BRANCH_NAME=$(
      curl -s \
        --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
        "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/commits/$MR_BRANCH_LAST_COMMIT_SHA/merge_requests" |\
        jq -r '.[0].source_branch'
    )
```

I found that workaround here:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/run-job-in-ci-pipeline-only-on-merge-branch-into-the-master-and-get-merged-branch-name/24195/5

Comment: Note that you have to omit the space after `PRIVATE-TOKEN:` like so: `--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$CI_PRIVATE_TOKEN"` - see: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/4781#note_88220042

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation. If there was a `hotfix/xxxxx` branch, when pushed, it could go through full pipeline, but after merge request to `master` is approved, only `build` and `deploy` jobs should run, skipping all the tests in order to get changes to prod ASAP. If any other branch was merged to `master` full pipeline should run.

---

The solution for us was to use commit message title from the approved merge request:

```
.merged_hotfix_to_master: &merged_hotfix_to_master
                     "$CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^Merge branch 'hotfix\\// 
                        && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == 'master'"
    
.skip-for-hotfix-merge-to-master-rule:
  rules:
    - if: *merged_hotfix_to_master
      when: never
```

So if the commit message title started with `Merge branch 'hotfix/` and the target branch was `master` job can be skipped. Rule was added where appropriate:

```
some-test:
  extends: .tests-common
  stage: test
    - !reference [.skip-for-hotfix-merge-to-master-rule, rules]
    - if: *only-master-branch
```

Not the most elegant solution, but I don't see the reason to change merge request default message anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the `export` command and saw that only two predefined variables contained the source branch (as part of a string), one being `$CI_COMMIT_TITLE`. It returned:

```
declare -x CI_COMMIT_TITLE="Merge branch 'source-branch-name' into 'master'"
```

I had the same thought process as @boombar – using the `CI_COMMIT_TITLE` string to retrieve the source branch name. I split the string and set the source branch substring as a variable, like so:

```
- SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME=`echo $CI_COMMIT_TITLE | cut -d"'" -f 2`
```

Also agree that it's not the most elegant way of going about it, but as long as the default message doesn't change, you're golden.