# Do not run Git Pipelines when merge TO and FROM default branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

Please help with gitlab-ci.yml the goal is to do not run pipeline when creating a copy branch from **product** named with **auto-*** and do not run pipeline when merging back from **auto-*** to **product** branch. BUT run pipeline when just commit to **auto-*** or to **product** and run pipeline for **product** when merging to it from non **auto-*** branches . Tried bellow workflow but does not work... pipeline runs all the time(

In short I do not want to run pipeline when creating for example **auto-testing** branch from **product** and do not want to run it when merging **auto-testing** back to **product**

By the way pipeline uploads to the same folder for both **product** and **auto-***

```
workflow:
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^auto-(.*)$/'
      when: never  
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^auto-(.*)$/'
      when: never 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "product" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^auto-(.*)$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `'$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"` only covers pipelines that run within merge requests, not those that run after you merge it. GitLab does not differentiate Merge-Request results from normal pushes, so for those the variable will hold `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=push`.

In fact, there is no built-in way in GitLab to determine where a MR came frome that triggered a pipeline. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877180/gitlab-ci-get-source-branch-after-merge-request-has-been-accepted) you can use a workaround to get this information using the API.

Maybe a solution for you could be to built a pipeline that runs, requests the source branch using the API and immediately stops if the source branch starts with `auto-*`.